# How to put record of type MAP <STRING, ARRAY <STRING>> to AWS Glue using firehose python SDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

As a start, I have created a simple Glue schema and an AWS delivery stream. With simple types such as string or float, I am able to put a record to the delivery stream and see it transformed into a parquet file on S3 by using the following Python code:

```
import json

import boto3

STREAM_NAME = 'TEST-STREAM'


def generate(stream_name, kinesis_client, output=True):
    count = 0
    total = 2000
    while count < total:
        count += 1
        response = kinesis_client.put_record(
            DeliveryStreamName=stream_name,
            Record={
                'Data': json.dumps({'id': '1234', 'value': 0.4})
            }
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate(STREAM_NAME, boto3.client('firehose', region_name='eu-west-1'))
```

However, when I add a field with the type `MAP <STRING, ARRAY <STRING>>` to my schema and call the put_record API with the additional data, the following error occurs:

```
response = kinesis_client.put_record(
            DeliveryStreamName=stream_name,
            Record={
                'Data': json.dumps({'id': '1234', 'value': 0.4, 'data':['a','b']})
            }
        )
```

Error:

```
Data does not match the schema. org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.openx.data.jsonserde.json.JSONObject
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Shot in the dark: I wonder if there's a conflict with the key name `data`. What happens if you try renaming the key?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried ... but the same error happens